# How can I track commands executed in a terminal ( without bash_history )

Tags: linux, logs, monitoring

I'm writing a program that tracks user activities, and basically tries to automate things that can be.

I'm currently trying to monitor programs that user uses often from command line. But just knowing is not enough, I need data along the lines of when such command were executed, working directory etc.

My current solution is a set of python scripts, that on start up, go through PATH and make a dummy python script for every program found in PATH. When the user tries to use those commands,those scripts are called instead(by prepending the path to script, to the PATH) each of such script passes it's name and args to another script that logs the information and then calls whatever was originally typed on the terminal( by altering the PATH). Its a rather messy solution. I'm sure there's some straight forward way of doing this.

Also, It's be great If I could get the data on commands being executed in real ( or almost real ) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at auditd? If not see this slideshow about Linux audit system. It does provide most of the facilities that you are describing and in a much more standard and fool proof way.

http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/audit_ids_2011.pdf